# <li> element toggle between different background colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the background color of the button based upon the class. Why it is not going back after second click?

```js
var $begin1 = $(".begin1").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var buttonState = $(this).attr("class");
  if (buttonState != 'pressed') {
    $begin1.removeClass('pressed');
    $(this).addClass('pressed');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('pressed');
    $(this).addClass('unpressed');
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.begin1.unpressed,
.begin2.unpressed {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
li.begin1.pressed,
li.begin2.pressed {
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="begin1 unpressed">
  <h2>Button</h2>
</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nrebaL00/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code greatly. Apply the default styling from the beginning and you don't need an `.unpressed` class.

The issue with using `.attr( 'class' )` is that it will retrieve all the classes applied to the element as a string. Performing a check like `if ( 'a' === $el.attr( 'class' ) )` won't work where `$el` is `<li class="a b c">` as `$el.attr( 'class' )` would return `'a b c'` and not `'a'`. Which is why your check was failing after the first click. This kind of check would be good for `.hasClass()`.

`e.prevendDefault()` is not required for an `<li>`, so remove that.

**Note:** the selector I used for jQuery is pretty generic. You may need to increase it's specificity if there are other `<li>` on the page that don't require the functionality. Something along the lines of adding a class to the `<ul>` and using that as the part of the jQuery selector. i.e. `<ul class="clicky-mcclickens">` and `$( '.clicky-mcclickens li' )`.

```js
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('pressed');
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.pressed {
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>Button 1</h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Button 2</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Sometimes you need more control than simply adding/removing a class when an element is clicked. In those instances you can use `.hasClass()` to check if the element has the class in question and apply the appropriate action.

Comment: Don't forget the `unpressed` class too

Comment: `.unpressed` may or may not be required depending on requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is much more complex than it needs to be; you can just call `toggleClass()` like this:

```
var $begin1 = $(".begin1").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('pressed unpressed');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nrebaL00/2/)

Note that `e.preventDefault()` is redundant for an `li` element as it has no default behaviour to prevent.

Comment: I have never seen the toggleClass function. This is very sharp. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would use toggleClass instead of adding and removing manually. This seems to work:

```
var $begin1 = $(".begin1").click( function(e) {
    $begin1.toggleClass('pressed');
});
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of check the complete string of the class of the element you can check if the element has specific class using `hasClass`:

```js
var $begin1 = $(".begin1").click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!$(this).hasClass('pressed')){
    $begin1.removeClass('unpressed');
    $(this).addClass('pressed');
  } else{
    $(this).removeClass('pressed');
    $(this).addClass('unpressed');
  }
});
```

```css
li{
  list-style-type: none;
}
.begin1.unpressed,
.begin2.unpressed {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
li.begin1.pressed,
li.begin2.pressed{
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <li class="begin1 unpressed"><h2>Button</h2></li>
```

The problem with using the `attr('class')` is that you can't know what exactly will be the final string.

Comment: Thank You! Your help is tremendous

Comment: Will appreciate if the downvoter will give an explanation!

Comment: I believe it was because he believes the .toggleClass function would eliminate a lot of extra code

Comment: @RyeGuy, this is not a reason for down vote, it can be a comment. A down vote is if the answer is not correct/not relevant/unclear/unhelpful.

Comment: Agreed. I gave you an up vote so it evens out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your js with:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".begin1").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("pressed");
 });
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the `unpressed` class too

Comment: no need unpressed because <li class="begin1 unpressed"><h2>Button</h2></li>